# firefox doesn't open google or gmail

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, security, browser, gmail

Recently I have encountered problems with firefox opening google and gmail.  Since firefox is one of my favorite browsers I'd like to fix it.  It was working quite well till yesterday.  I managed to open google and gmail with other browsers and also open other search engines pages with firefox. I tried various things from reinstalling firefox to disabling av and changing some configuration files for firefox but nothing helps.  I got messages like that:

You have asked Firefox to connect securely to www.google.pl, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.

Normally, when you try to connect securely, sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified.
What Should I Do?

If you usually connect to this site without problems, this error could mean that someone is trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't continue.

```
This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.

www.google.pl uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown. The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates. An additional root certificate may need to be imported. (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)
```

At this point I'd like to add security exception, but there is no button for that displayed. Does it have anything to do with firefox dumping google for yahoo?;) http://www.cnet.com/news/in-major-shift-firefox-to-use-yahoo-search-by-default-in-us/

Answer (score 3):

The message tells you why there is no exception button: **because (FF thinks) the site uses HSTS**, which means it *does not want* connections that aren't secure, and Firefox *honors that request*. But:
https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json includes google.pl (and google.com.pl!) on the supposedly shared preload list but my FF (ESR38.4 Windows) apparently does not have this entry (and has a much smaller list overall) according to my profile's SiteSecurityServiceState.txt . And when I connect to addresses in the three different ranges I get for www.google.pl from my ISP's DNS, Level3, and the delegated and apparently authoritative ns[12].google.com, respectively 63.117.14.184 74.125.226.191 173.194.123.87 -- which are the same address ranges I get for www.google.com -- I get (valid) replies with **no STS** -- and with certificates as expected under Google Internet Authority G2, which chains to GeoTrust and conditionally Equifax which are both trusted by all my browsers and clients.

But google likes to send people from different countries/regions to different DNS and different servers, so you may be connecting somewhere different from me correctly -- or incorrectly, due to an attack or possibly mistake. I'd suggest you first check that your Firefox's truststore "Authorities" contains "GeoTrust Global CA" (fingerprint DE:28:F4:A4:FF:E5:B9:2F:A3:C5:03:D1:A3:49:A7:F9:96:2A:82:12) and/or "Equifax Secure CA" (D2:32:09:AD:23:D3:14:23:21:74:E4:0D:7F:9D:62:13:97:86:63:3A); and if so look at the cert chain(s?) in your other browser (assuming the same network connection) and see what you are actually getting and what root(s) it(they) chain to.

If you're on Windows (you didn't say) one possibility is your traffic is intercepted by an AV or proxy that has a fake root in the Windows cert store, used by both IE and Chrome but not Firefox.

ADDED: **to check Firefox truststore** on the Tools menu choose item Options then category Advanced and click the View Certificates button.
If you don't have menu bar displayed, hit ALT briefly; or just do ALT+T, O.
On the Certificate Manager window, choose Authorities tab. The entries 
are not all in alphabetical order, but the ones you want (GeoTrust 
and Equifax) are. For a particular entry, doubleclick (or select and click View button) and it displays a bunch of information with the fingerprints (currently SHA256 and SHA1) at the bottom.

**To check the cert chain** on another browser (that does connect) depends on the browser. For IE 9-11 (I no longer have older to check) click the padlock at the right of the address bar then the View Certificates link, then Certification Path tab.
Or on the View menu choose Security Report then View Certificates etc.
I don't have Edge. For Chrome click the padlock at the left of the address bar, then the Connection tab, then Certificate Information link, then Certification Path tab.

Reading path from the bottom up it should have some name involving google (exact one doesn't matter right now), then `Google Internet Authority G2`, then `GeoTrust Global CA` either at the top or next to the top and `Equifax Secure CA` at the top. If not, give details about what you do have.

Comment: Thank you for your exhausting response.  I'm on Windows.  I have tried to disable av and checked proxy.  Could you please tell me how to check "your Firefox's truststore Authorities and other things you mentioned?  I also thought that this could've been a man in the middle attack so I installed bitdefender (free edition), previously I was using another av.  Once I installed bitdefender I managed to open google.pl and gmail, but it was slowing my system and some aps couldn'be be started so I uninstalled it.  Then once again problem with google and gmail was there.

Comment: @aretai too much for comments, see edit.